# Why when I clicked on subtract or multiply button still doing the add function?

Tags: javascript, dom

My `if` statements don't work because I said to the statements to make subtract, if `subtractOp` (subtract button is clicked) were click and this operator still doing add function.

```
let firstValue;
let secondValue;

addOp.addEventListener('click', function() {
    firstValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
    outPut.innerText = '';
});

subtractOp.addEventListener('click', function() {
    firstValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
    outPut.innerText = '';
});

multiplyOp.addEventListener('click', function() {
    firstValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
    outPut.innerText = '';
});

equals.addEventListener('click', function() {
    secondValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
    if(addOp) {
        outPut.innerText = add(firstValue, secondValue);
        console.log(add(firstValue, secondValue));
    } else if(subtractOp) {
        outPut.innerText = subtract(firstValue, secondValue);
        console.log(subtract(firstValue, secondValue));
    } else if(multiplyOp) {
        outPut.innerText = multiply(firstValue, secondValue);
        console.log(multiply(firstValue, secondValue));
    }
});
```

Comment: HTMLElements are truthy. `if(addOp) {` will always be fulfilled.

Comment: addOp is a HTML element. It is not a true or false value. Although you are *allowed* to use it as the condition for an if statement, it doesn't make any sense to do so.

Comment: How can I do to make operate it. I don't know how yet.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your if/else statement in the equals handler is wrong.

```
    if(addOp) {
        outPut.innerText = add(firstValue, secondValue);
        console.log(add(firstValue, secondValue));
    } else if(subtractOp) {
        outPut.innerText = subtract(firstValue, secondValue);
        console.log(subtract(firstValue, secondValue));
    } else if(multiplyOp) {
        outPut.innerText = multiply(firstValue, secondValue);
        console.log(multiply(firstValue, secondValue));
    }
```

`if(addOp)` always returns true because `addOp` is an HTML element. You need to add booleans to determine what operation you wish to perform.

Comment: I wish to perform the add, subtract or multiply when the user click on one of those. How can I do that?